# Internal document references Latex \label \ref via pandoc to HTML screw up for Epub generation

Tags: pandoc, latex2html, epub

Basically Pandoc to HTML works really well

pandoc -s ABC.tex -o ABC.html --citeproc --standalone --number-sections

The generated (and with Jutoh post processed) Epub works fine on Kindle or Adobe Digital Editions.

However there is one issue that is still screwing up the usage of the resulting Epub in submitting it to Amazon etc.

When you have a section and label it i.e. \section{ABC}\label{se:ABC} it creates links like

`<li><a href="#se:ABC"><span class="toc-section-number">4</span> ABC</a>`

And this #se:ABC is then flagged as unsuitable links within the ebook. It works funnily enough in HTML pre-Ebook incorporation.

Is there anything in Pandoc to change the definition of these links ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twoside]{memoir} 

\usepackage{graphicx}

%--------------------
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} %Allow separation
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}

\title{ABC}

\author{ABC}

\begin{document}

\section{ABC}\label{se:ABC}

Let us go to section DEF \ref{se:DEF}

\section{DEF}\label{se:DEF}

Let us go to section ABC \ref{se:DEF}

\end{document}
```

Then

```
pandoc -s Test.tex -o Test.html --citeproc --toc --standalone --number-sections
```

Which results in ...

```
<li><a href="#se:ABC"><span class="toc-section-number">1</span> ABC</a></li>
<li><a href="#se:DEF"><span class="toc-section-number">2</span> DEF</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<h1 data-number="1" id="se:ABC"><span class="header-section-number">1</span> ABC</h1>
<p>Let us go to section DEF <a href="#se:DEF" data-reference-type="ref" data-reference="se:DEF">2</a></p>
<h1 data-number="2" id="se:DEF"><span class="header-section-number">2</span> DEF</h1>
<p>Let us go to section ABC <a href="#se:DEF" data-reference-type="ref" data-reference="se:DEF">2</a></p>
```

Comment: Why is this labelled `latex-2.09`? a format no-one should have been using for the last 25+ years.

Comment: You probably need to provide more code instead of textual description otherwise others have no change helping you

Comment: Comments are not for long pieces of code, please move those into your question instead